# Can't add AWS Workmail to Thunderbird (no error to speak of)

Tags: thunderbird, amazon-workmail

Trying to add an AWS Workmail account to thunderbird. It says it sees the config, I put in my password, it brings up the amazon workmail login screen as a smaller-than-usual pop-up modal that asks me to log into AWS Workmail. I am able to do this, but all that happens is that I can operate my email from the modal and thunderbird hangs forever on 'checking password...'

Very frustrating.

Anyone else had this specific issue. Reinstalling thunderbird doesn't work.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hCzg.png)

Comment: Oh, and if you close the AWS Workmail pop-up, thunderbird gives an actual error and says "authentication window was closed too early"